# How can I use grep as cat

Tags: bash, grep

I am creating a script that parses some files and greps out the necessary information.

I have set up many different variables in arrays that search for different aspects in the files.
  e.g. dates, locations, types.

However I wanted to make each of these variables optional which is where I run into an issue.

the syntax of the command would have been simple
`grep ${dates} filename | grep ${locations} | grep ${types}`

However, due to variables being optional, the above won't work if a variable is unset.

I was trying to find a way to get grep to find anything (i.e. like `egrep .* filename`)
that way I could set the variables to the proper regex and have the command still run.

unfortunately, when I set the variable to equal '*' it freezes, when I set it to '.*' it just greps everything from every file in the current directory and when I leave the variable blank it takes the filename as the variable and waits for a filename.

is there anyway that I can set a variable so that `grep $variable file` outputs the same as cat would?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `grep` to act like `cat` use an empty string as a search pattern, i.e. `grep ""`.  Therefore to make some of those variables optional, but not have piped `grep`s fail, just quote the variables:

```
grep "${dates}" filename | grep "${locations}" | grep "${types}"
```

Demonstration.  Search {250,255,260...280} for the digits *5*, *2*, and *7*:

```
x=5  y=2  z=7 ; seq 250 5 280 | grep "$x" | grep "$y" | grep "$z"
275
```

Now unset two of the variables, and it still works:

```
unset x y ; seq 250 5 280 | grep "$x" | grep "$y" | grep "$z"
270
275
```

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any $dates in filename then there is nothing to feed the rest of the pipeline.

I think the best way to do it is to grep for each string separately.

If you get a match, then grep for the next string.

Answer (score -1):

Can you post the source file and a target output. From your question it sounds like you just need to use grep -E in conjunction with the | pipe delimiter.

```
grep -E "${dates}|${locations}|${types}" fileName
```

The above line should automatically get you every occurrence of the any of the patterns. This is not even a regex yet.

Comment: You need not use *extended* regex options, simply `grep "$dates\|$locations\|$types" filename` is fine. (if you need extended regex, then, of course, use it, but if not, basic `grep` is fine)

Comment: The OP describes using shell pipes `|`, not logical *OR*s.  Compare `seq 10 5 50 | grep -E '2|5'`, (find *2* OR *5*), to `seq 10 5 50 | grep '5' | grep '2'`, (find *2* AND *5*).